# How to create different layer of background for pygame packed into one class

Tags: python, pygame

I'm really new to pygame and Python classes. I tried to create a game with different layers.

- Layer 1: gameplay
- Layer 2: HP: Position:...

It looks a little bit like this:

[image]

I think the problem with my code is that i did not know how to use class properly. And I use the wrong method to create a layer for my game.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

pygame.init()

colors = [(255, 255, 255), (204, 229, 255), (0, 0, 0)] #white, light_blue, black


X_AXIS = [x for x in range(11)]
Y_AXIS = ("X A B C D E F G H I").split()

class character:
    pass

class Gameplay:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        logo = pygame.image.load(r'logo.png')
        pygame.display.set_caption("Battle Royale")
        pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
    def background_layer(self):
        self.game_surf = pygame.surface.Surface((800,600))
        game_surf.fill(colors[0])
        display.blit(game_surf, (0, 0))
    
    
gameplay = Gameplay(1300, 760)

while True:
    gameplay.background_layer()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pass
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Weird to have "prairie" right next to the ocean, though!

Comment: I see only one layer in your code - `background_layer()`. First you have to create second function which draws next layer - ie. `information_layer()` - and put code in this function and run it after you run `background_layer()`. BTW: if you plan to blit another surface then better convert it to RGBA `.convert_alpha()`) - and first fill all pixels with `(0,0,0,255)` to get transparent surface.

Comment: you could create `self.game_surf` only once - in `__init__` - and if it will have always the same content then you could also fill ite in `__init__`. And later you could run only `display.blit(self.game_surf, (0, 0))`

Comment: BTW: you forgot `self.` in `display.blit(self.game_surf, (0, 0))` and `self.game_surf.fill(colors[0])`

Comment: do you get error message when you run it? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: shorter: `X_AXIS = list(range(11))` and `Y_AXIS = list("XABCDEFGHI")`

Comment: you also forgot `self.` in `self.display.blit(...)`

Comment: and you forgot `pygame.display.flip()` to send it from buffer to screen

Answer (score 0):

First few mistakes:

You forgot `self.` in few places and it should gives you error messages (but you didn't mention it).

You forgot `pygame.display.flip()` to send from buffer to screen.

---

If you want other layers then you should add other functions to draw them.

At this moment I see only `def background_layer()` but you could add other functions for other layers and later execute them in loop - like this:

```
        while True:

            self.draw_background()
            self.draw_player()
            self.draw_grid()
            self.draw_info()

            pygame.display.flip()
            
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                # ... code ...
```

---

Minimal working code with other changes.

```
import sys
import pygame

# --- constants ----  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` for constants

COLORS = [(255, 255, 255), (204, 229, 255), (0, 0, 0)] #white, light_blue, black

X_AXIS = list(range(11))
Y_AXIS = list("XABCDEFGHI")

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes

class Character:
    pass

class Game:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        pygame.init()
        
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        #self.display_rect = self.display.get_rect()
        
        pygame.display.set_caption("Battle Royale")
        
        #logo = pygame.image.load(r'logo.png')
        #pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
        
        self.layer_background = pygame.surface.Surface((800, 600))
        self.layer_background.fill(COLORS[0])
        self.layer_background_rect = self.layer_background.get_rect()
        
        self.pos = 'X0'
        self.hp = 100
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
        
    def draw_background(self):
        self.display.blit(self.layer_background, self.layer_background_rect)
        
    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, 800, 50):
            pygame.draw.line(self.display, COLORS[2], (x, 0), (x, 600))

        for y in range(0, 600, 50):
            pygame.draw.line(self.display, COLORS[2], (0, y), (800, y))

    def draw_info(self):
        text_image = self.font.render(f"POS: {self.pos}", False, COLORS[0])
        text_rect  = text_image.get_rect(x=880, y=350)
        self.display.blit(text_image, text_rect)

        text_image = self.font.render(f"HP: {self.hp}", False, COLORS[0])
        text_rect  = text_image.get_rect(x=880, y=450)
        self.display.blit(text_image, text_rect)

    def run(self):

        while True:
            self.draw_background()
            #self.draw_player()
            self.draw_grid()
            self.draw_info()
            pygame.display.flip()
            
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    pass
                elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
        
# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions

# empty

# --- main ---

game = Game(1300, 760)
game.run()
```

[image]

Comment: Does pygame.surface.Surface(500,760) mean creating a new surface on display. And does it like Unity when I can changing the content in only that layer (draw_info(self)) (such as POS and HP)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Surface` creates area in memory on which you can draw and later `blit()` puts it on `display` (which is also a `Surface`). In `draw_info()` I draw text directly on `display` but you can create separated `Surface` and draw text on this surface. But you can't only change text on this surface - you have to  blit it in every loop on `display`. PyGame is not big famework like `Unity` (which may have layers and displays them automatically on display) - PyGame ist only low-level library and some elements you have to do manually in code.